# Number of connected components after removing a finite number of points from a figure

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = \{(x,y): x,y \in \mathbb{R}; x^2 + y^2 = 1\} \cup ([-1, 1] \times \{0\}) \cup (0 \times [-1,1])$.

Let $n_0 = \max\{k : k < \infty$, there are $k$ distinct points $p_1, p_2, \dots p_k$ s.t. $X - \{p_1, p_2, \dots  p_k\}$ is connected $\}$. **Then what is the value of $n_0$ ?**

Let $\{q_0, q_1, \dots q_{n_0+1}\}$ be $n_0 +1$ distinct points of $X$. Let $Y = X - \{q_0, q_1, \dots q_{n_0+1}\}$. **What is the maximum number of possible connected components of $Y$?**

*My Attempt*

I have drawn a figure of $X$. Then I have selected points randomly to make $X$ disconnected. Maximum $4$ points I can remove such that the figure stay connected. If T remove $5$ points them I can get maximum $8$ connected components. This is true answer by a trial and error method.

[image]

I am looking for a proper mathematical approach to solve this type of problem. I want a systematic way to find it out.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We can remove points from straight line, so we can remove $7$ points from $X$ to stay connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Think about this object as a graph. You have two operations: delete the vertex and cut the edge. For example for (1) if you only cut edges then you must stop when the graph left is just a tree. Also, you can just look at the cases with vertex-deleting in the same way (notice, that you can delete one or two vertices). For the second problem notice, that each connected component has at least two vertices, and by our operations you can not increase the number of vertices more then by two.

Comment: Is the question related to graph theory?

Comment: for topological graph theory for sure:

your space is a topological graph